# Abstract genetic type in one-to-many relation trouble

Tags: hibernate, jpa, generics, kotlin, spring-data

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
import javax.persistence.CascadeType
import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue
import javax.persistence.GenerationType
import javax.persistence.Id
import javax.persistence.Inheritance
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn
import javax.persistence.OneToMany
import javax.persistence.OneToOne
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator
import javax.persistence.Table

@Entity
@Table(schema = "app_db", name = "fam")
class Family(

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        val id: Int? = null,

        @OneToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
        @JoinColumn(name = "child_id")
        var firstChild: Child,

        @OneToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
        @JoinColumn(name = "fam_id")
        @JvmSuppressWildcards // without it gives: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Collection has neither generic type or OneToMany.targetEntity() defined: com.betoola.integrapi.entity.schema.Family.children
        var children: List<Child>

)

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
abstract class Child(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "schemaGen")
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "schemaGen", sequenceName = "TEMP_SEQUENCE", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
        val id: Int? = null,

        var name: String?)

@Entity
@Table(schema = "app_db", name = "daugh")
class Daughter(id: Int?, name: String) :
        Child(id, name)

@Entity
@Table(schema = "app_db", name = "son")
class Son(id: Int?, name: String) :
        Child(id, name)
```

and to test using :

```
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner

@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest
class RepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var repo: FamTypeGeneralRepository

    @Test
    fun writeSonProp() {
        val family = Family(null, Son(null, "Petya"), listOf())
        repo.save(family)
        val findAll = repo.findAll()
        println(findAll)

    }

    @Test
    fun writeDaughProp() {
        val family = Family(null, Daughter(null, "Nastya"), listOf())
        repo.save(family)
        val findAll = repo.findAll()
        println(findAll)

    }

    @Test
    fun writeAllProp() {
        val firstChild = Daughter(null, "Nastya")

        val family = Family(null, firstChild, listOf(firstChild))
        repo.save(family)
        val findAll = repo.findAll()
        println(findAll)

    }
```

The part with one-to-one relation works perfectly so 2 tests pass, I also can load all children if they already written in the base, The problem is: I can't write family entity as cascade.  It produces: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "CHILD" not found; SQL statement:
update child set fam_id=? where id=? [42102-199]

I've tryed this

```
@MappedSuperclass
abstract class Child(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "schemaGen")
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "schemaGen", sequenceName = "TEMP_SEQUENCE", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
        val id: Int? = null,

        var name: String?)

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@Table(schema = "app_db", name = "daugh")
class Daughter(id: Int?, name: String) :
        Child(id, name)

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@Table(schema = "app_db", name = "son")
class Son(id: Int?, name: String) :
        Child(id, name)
```

get org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on **.entity.schema.Family.firstChild references an unknown entity: **.entity.schema.Child
here is SQL migration

```
CREATE SEQUENCE TEMP_SEQUENCE;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS app_db.son
(
    ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    NAME varchar(250),
    FAM_ID INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS app_db.daugh
(
    ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    NAME varchar(250),
    FAM_ID INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS app_db.fam
(
    ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    CHILD_ID INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
);
```

Appreciate any help